# Web Service in Eclipse/Java not recognizing my Types

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I created a Dynamic Web Project, and put one class in it - this super simple one method class:

```
public class StoreServer {

    private int numberOfItems = 50;

    public int getNumberOfItems(){
        return numberOfItems;
    }
}
```

I right clicked on it, selected `Create Web Service`, followed the wizard and everything worked great.

Then, I added another class. This one called `StoreItem`.

**StoreItem**

```
public class StoreItem {

}
```

**StoreServer**

```
public class StoreServer {

    private int numberOfItems = 50;

    public int getNumberOfItems(){
        return numberOfItems;
    }

    public int getCostOfItem(StoreItem storeItem){
        return 10; //dollars
    }
}
```

Now when I run this, I get all sorts of errors.
Why can't Eclipse/Java/Tomcat recognize other types? How do I get this to run properly?

```
SEVERE: Unable to deploy typemapping: {http://DefaultNamespace}StoreItem
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultNamespace.StoreItem
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getLanguageSpecificType(WSDDTypeMapping.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 25, 2015 3:25:44 PM org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment <init>
INFO: Ignoring non-fatal exception
org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDNonFatalException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultNamespace.StoreItem
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultNamespace.StoreItem
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getLanguageSpecificType(WSDDTypeMapping.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDNonFatalException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultNamespace.StoreItem
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultNamespace.StoreItem
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getLanguageSpecificType(WSDDTypeMapping.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:561)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:561)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: have you added your java classes in web.xml? Log states ClassNotFoundException. check your path as well

Comment: Well I didn't add `StoreServer` to `web.xml` but it worked. I don't think that can be the problem

Comment: add to web.xml as well as check your path because ClassNotFoundException means program is not finding your java class